# Probability density of $X_1 − 2X_2$, where $X_1, X_2$ independent and exponentially distributed.

Tags: probability-theory, convolution, density-function, exponential-distribution, fake-proofs

### Problem

---

Consider $X_1, X_2 \sim \varepsilon(1)$ independent and define $T = X_1 - 2X_2$.

I want to calculate the probability density function (pdf) of $T$, denoted by $f_T$, which can be obtained by convolving the pdfs of $X_1$ with $-2X_2$.

My result is
\begin{equation}
f_T(t) =\begin{cases}
    \frac{2}{3} \, e^{t/2} & t < 0 \\
    \frac{2}{3} \, e^{-t} & t \geq 0
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Unfortunately, this pdf is too large by a factor of 2.
Below, I show my calculations that led here.
Please help me identify the error.

### Calculations

---

Let $f_1$ denote the pdf of $X_1$ and $f_2$ denote the pdf of $-2X_2$.
Using this notation, we calculate $f_2$ by deriving its respective cumulative distribution function (cdf), denoted by $F_2$.

For $F_2$ we obtain:

\begin{align}
  F_2(x) &= P(-2X_2 \leq x) \\
  &= P \left (X_2 \geq -\frac{x}{2} \right) \\
  &= \int_{ -x/2}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{[0, \infty)}(y) \cdot e^{-y} dy \\
  &=\begin{cases}
    1 & x > 0 \\
    e^{x/2} & x \leq 0
  \end{cases}
\end{align}

Deriving $F_2$ yields:
\begin{equation}
f_2(x) = \frac{\partial F_2(x)}{\partial x} =\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty, 0]}(x) \cdot e^{x/2}
\end{equation}

We now convolve $f_1$ with $f_2$:
\begin{align}
  f_T(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_1(x) f_2(t - x) dx \\
  &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{[0, \infty)}(x) \cdot e^{-x} \cdot \mathbf{1}_{(-\infty, 0]}(t - x) \cdot e^{(t - x)/2} \, dx \\
  &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{[t, \infty)}(x) \cdot e^{(t - 3x)/2} \, dx \\
  &= \int_{\text{max}(0, \, t)}^{\infty} e^{(t - 3x)/2} dx \\
  &= \frac{2}{3} \, e^{\, t/2 \, - \, 3 \cdot \text{max}(0, \, t) /2} \\
  &=\begin{cases}
    \frac{2}{3} \, e^{t/2} & t < 0 \\
    \frac{2}{3} \, e^{-t} & t \geq 0
  \end{cases}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a factor of $1/2$ in the density $f_2(x)$:  differentiating $$F_2(x) = \begin{cases}1, & x > 0 \\ e^{x/2}, & x \le 0\end{cases}$$ yields $$f_2(x) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}} e^{x/2}, \quad x \le 0.$$

Comment: Thanks! Of course the error occured in the easiest step :-)

Comment: @Lime91 If the error had been in a more complex step, you probably would have caught it right away!  Often it is because a step in a proof or calculation is simple that we tend to overlook it or develop a blind spot.  It happens all the time to me.

Comment: To me it is uplifting to hear that others face this issue as well. Thanks again.